# How to include FMPP as a maven dependency not as a plugin

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, frontend, fmpp

I want to write a FMPP Front End application but the official documentation do not explains how to include the FMPP library in a maven project, but the plugin. So i want to know how to include the library so i can extend the `fmpp.setting.Settings;` object.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the **fmpp-maven-plugin** dependencies :), so just include something like this in the dependencies' block in the pom.xml

```
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.fmpp</groupId>
        <artifactId>fmpp</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.15</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then use **Clean and Build** and try using in any java file:

```
import fmpp.setting.Settings;
```

Thats it!

Comment: Or, simply searching for "fmpp" on http://search.maven.org/ gives the same result immediately.